# Crystal XI - Can you split or filter a single datasource to create multiple charts?

Tags: crystal-reports, charts, datasource

I have a dataset which has a daily count spanning over several months and I want to create a graph showing the daily counts however I want to have a separate chart for each month. Is this possible to do by isolating each month?

For example if I have

2009/1/1 45
2009/1/2 21
2009/1/3 11
2009/1/4 11
2009/2/1 34
2009/2/2 45
2009/2/3 11
2009/2/4 34

Chart A would filter the dataset so only January's data would be displayed
Chart B would filter the dataset so only Febuary's data would be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Using Chart Expert click the 'Order...' button and set Chart Sort Order to 'specified order' then define the month you want to see. A new tab will appear called 'Others'. Click it and check 'Discard all others'. The chart now only should display data for the specified period.